# Как привести {{ request.user.username }} к строке?

Tags: django, jinja2

Проблема заключается в том, что `{{ request.user.username }}` отдаёт не строку, из-за чего не получается проверить содержимое через if.
К примеру, результатом вывода на шаблон `{{ request.user.username }}` будет admin, но при этом `{% if request.user.username == 'admin'%}` возвращает false.
Как можно это исправить?

Comment: Вы уверены, что вы хотели написать именно `'admin '` а не `'admin'`? Это вообще-то разные строки

Comment: Исправил. Имел в виду 'admin'.

Comment: И это тоже не работает? Покажите вывод `print(repr(request.user.username))` где-нибудь в вашей вьюхе

Comment: Выводит 'admin'

Answer (score 0):

Хотел б узнать, зачем делать условия от имени пользователя, если можно использовать для определения статуса пользователя **if requets.user.is_superuser**
Ну а если необходимо при помощи имени пользвателя, то можно создать переменную внутри вьюшки, по типу

```
def home(request):
    admin = "admin"
    return render(request, 'template', {'admin' : admin})
```

А затем прописать **{% if request.user.username == admin %}**

Comment: Для сравнивания адреса текущей страницей со страницей профиля текущего пользователя, чтобы в свою очередь подсветить элемент меню.
Этот метод:  `{% if {{request.path}}" == "/profile/{{ request.user.username }}/" %}` не работает, при этом, если вместо `{{ request.user.username }}` написать просто имя пользователя, то всё работает. 
Сейчас проверил на вьюшке, там этот же код почему-то работает. В принципе, решение проблемы найдено.